# Which song plays in episode 56 at 11:32

Tags: music, bleach

There's a song at around 11:32 that I really want to know but can't find.

I've looked at the sound track and can't find it.
I've looked nearly everywhere but to no source!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this sound track does not actually have a name. You can find it by googling ~ BLEACH OST - Shiro Sagisu - BL_86.  I think BL_86 was the official title of this sound track.

[Youtube video with soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfjYk0UK2ec)

Edit: Upon further diggin. BL_86 is the offical title of this soundtrack. It appears in Bleach 5th Anniversary Box CD 1.

Comment: @Seb No worries :)

Comment: @Seb Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped – by clicking the checkmark icon under the up / down vote icons.